# Core Data, NSTableColumn bindings and custom NSCell

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm trying to display an array of `NSManagedObjects` in a `NSTableView` using a custom `NSCell` that is able to draw the managed object properly.

For that matter, the single column of my `NSTableView` is binded to the `arrangedObjects` of a `NSArrayController`.  I'm not using any key paths on the object.

I was under the impression that my `NSCell` subclass would receive a `setObjectValue:` message when the table view wants to draw a particular item, but this isn't happening.  But that wouldn't even work since the `NSManagedObjects` aren't conforming to the `Copying` protocol.

I suspect this is a common task and that there must be some simple way to do this, but I really don't see it right now.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Very similar to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409424/editable-nstableview-with-bindings-wont-set-values-in-model.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind to a specific property of the bound objects. If you really need one cell to draw the entire value, then you should bind to the `objectID`, as Martin suggests, but instead of re-fetching in the cell’s drawing code you can use the `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` delegate method to set the object as a value for a custom property of the cell from the array controller, avoiding both copying and fetching.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by binding the table column with the `objectID` keypath of the managed object model (which is `NSCopying` conforming).  The cell then retrieve the actual `NSManagedObject` using the ID.  It works like a charm!